# Find the angular momentum of a pulley system after the mass $M$ has descended through a height $h$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation

Two masses $M$ and $m$ are connected by a light spring going over a pulley of radius $r$. The pulley is free to rotate about its axis which is kept horizontal. The moment of inertia of the pulley about it's axis is $I$. The system is released from rest. Find the angular momentum of the system when the mass $M$ has descended through a height $h$. The string does not slip over the pulley.

[image]

**My attempt:-**

This question can be easily solved via conservation of energy and we find that the linear velocity $$v=\sqrt{\frac{2(M-m)gh}{M+m+\frac{I}{r^2}}}$$

Now to find the total momentum of the system $$mv=(M+m+\frac{I}{r})v$$

But in the book solution it's instead $$\left[ (M+m)r+\frac{I}{r} \right]v$$

The book has given the justification that angular momentum of mass $M$ is $Mvr$ and same for mass $m$.

How is this possible as both the blocks are undergoing linear motion, not rotational and their distance from the pulley cannot be $r$? What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: I haven't read the question thoroughly, but this question was presented excelently, and hence I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking you for angular momentum, not linear momentum. Your attempted solution, or whatever is
$$(M+m+\frac Ir)v$$
is not dimensionally consistent: $I/r$ cannot be added to masses.

You are supposed to take the pivot of the pulley, the both masses are at distance $r$ from this pivot. Their linear motion are of the type that adds to the angular momentum in precisely the correct way.

Comment: How are both the masses at a distance $ r$ from the pivot of pulley? And I don't understand the last line on how their linear motion are of the type that adds to the angular momentum in precisely the correct way?

Comment: The rope lines are $r$ away from the centre of the circle.

Comment: @SamarSidhu:  To elaborate on this point, see the [Wikipedia description of angular momentum of a point particle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Orbital_angular_momentum_in_two_dimensions)  The quantity $r_\perp$ there is the same as your $r$ here.